# Programa de hospital en Java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa más o menos como un hospital en el cual los usuarios que están siendo atendidos o que están dentro del hospital, no pueden volver a registrar que van a entrar hasta que hayan salido.

Si los usuarios están dentro del hospital, el programa responde que están dentro, si los usuarios estaban dentro, pero salieron, ahora si pueden volver a entrar, esta es la parte del programa de la que hablo

```
case 1:
    System.out.print("Ingrese el documento del paciente: ");
    docu=leer.next();
    if(enfermos.isEmpty()){
        System.out.print("Ingrese el nombre del paciente: ");
        nombre=leer.next();
        System.out.print("Ingrese los sintomas del paciente: ");
        sintomas=leer.next();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Paciente registrado con exito");
        String salida = null;
        String estado = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(entrada);
        System.out.println("Hora de ingreso al hospital "+estado);
        System.out.println("");
        ingresado=true;
        enfermos.add(new Paciente(docu,nombre,sintomas,entrada,salida,ingresado));
        break;
    }
    else{
        for (Paciente pacientes : enfermos) {
        if (pacientes.getDocu().equals(docu) && pacientes.isIngresado()==true && pacientes.isIngresado()!=false) {
        System.out.println("El paciente ya se encuentra ingresado en la clínica.");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        else if (pacientes.isIngresado()==false)){
        System.out.print("Ingrese el nombre del paciente: ");
        nombre=leer.next();
        System.out.print("Ingrese los sintomas del paciente: ");
        sintomas=leer.next();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Paciente registrado con exito");
        String salida = null;
        String estado = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(entrada);
        System.out.println("Hora de ingreso al hospital "+estado);
        System.out.println("");
        ingresado=true;
        enfermos.add(new Paciente(docu,nombre,sintomas,entrada,salida,ingresado));
        break;
        }
    }}
        break;
```

Hasta ahora si registro por ejemplo un usuario así (Documento:1,Nombre:1,Síntomas:1) está bien. Luego intento volver a registrarlo y lo rechaza, eso debe hacer el programa, el problema es cuando quiero registrar a un usuario 2, no se que condición escribir para permitir el registro de un segundo usuario. las variables:

```
String docu,nombre,sintomas;
Date entrada,salida;
boolean ingresado;
```

Comment: Bienvenido. El título es la cara visible de cualquier obra y se utiliza para dar una idea de qué se trata. Aunque no debemos juzgar un libro por su portada, la verdad es que no hay que descuidar esos detalles. El título es tan importante como lo que tienes para decir. Todos los principiantes podrían pensar en escribir *Hola, estoy aprendiendo a programar en Java*.

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo algunos cambios, a fin de hacer más legible tu código, y de paso ahorrar "tinta".

```
System.out.print( "Ingrese el documento del paciente: " );
docu = leer.next();                   
 
void nuevoIngreso( String docu ) {                  
    for( Paciente paciente : enfermos ) {                   
        if( pacientes.getDocu().equals( docu ) {
            if( paciente.isIngresado() == true ) {                    
                System.out.println( "El paciente ya se encuentra ingresado en la clínica." );
            }                   
            else if( paciente.isIngresado() == false ) {                   
                paciente.setIngresado();
            }
            return;  
        }
    }
    registrar();               
}                 
                    
                    
void registrar() {
     System.out.print( "Ingrese el nombre del paciente: " );                   
     nombre = leer.next();                   
     System.out.print( "Ingrese los sintomas del paciente: " );                   
     sintomas = leer.next();                   
     System.out.println("");                       
     String salida = null;
     String estado = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" ).format( entrada );                   
     System.out.println( "Hora de ingreso al hospital " + estado );                   
     System.out.println( "" );      
     ingresado = true; 
     enfermos.add( new Paciente( docu, nombre, sintomas, entrada, salida, ingresado )); 
     System.out.println( "Paciente registrado con exito" );                 
}
```

Como verás, es básicamente tu código... acortado.
Primero que nada separamos todo en métodos pequeños, son reutilizables y más faciles de mantener.
Eliminamos la verificación de lista vacía, el for de **nuevoIngreso()**, cumple la misma función, si la lista está vacía, no itera, y se llama a **registrar()**.
Si la lista no está vacía, recorre el array de "Pacientes" (enfermos... deberías mantener los nombres), corroborando si el documento coincide, obrando en consecuencia, después de lo cual sale del método con el **return**.
Esta no es la "solución final" (valga la horrible referencia), es solo un código que puede servir para orientarte.

Comment: Ya que te pones a simplificar ... Con eso de `paciente.isIngresado() == true` y el else-if siguiente comprobando si es false, se podría hacer algo ;-P

Comment: @RubioRic muy buena observación, debería ser **paciente.isIngresado()** en una, y en la otra **! paciente.isIngresado()**, gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Nada. De todas formas me referia a que se puede poner else directamente, sin condición. Suponiendo que isIngresado devuelve un boolean y no un Boolean.